# Turning Python code into a function

Tags: python, function

I am new to Python functions and am just practicing on my end. I wrote some basic code that asks user for a number input, 9 times, and then outputs either True or False based on > 100 or < 100.

This code works fine:

```
list_1 = []
count = 0
while count < 10:
    text = int(input('list a number:'))
    if text < 100:
        list_1.append(True)
    else:
        list_1.append(False)

    count = count + 1
print(list_1)
```

Now I want to convert that into a function (using For loop instead, for something different).  I tried a few versions and can't get it, nothing happens when i run this:

```
def foo():
    list_1 = []
    text = int(input('list a number:'))
    for x in range(10):
        if text > 100:
            list_1.append(True)
        else:
            list_1.append(False)
            return()
```

2 questions:

1. How do I write that function so it is actually useful and returns True or False?
2. Can someone show me a basic example of how using a function in this instance could be worthwhile?  Like how could I separate it from the first piece of code so it's actually useful in a different way?

I'd like to branch out from just writing pieces of code, to organizing it in a more efficient way

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to return a list of T/F? Or just one value? The `return` is useless as long as it is inside the loop.

Comment: @coldspeed  Id like to return a list of T/F  like the upper example does.  Thanks.  Maybe it's my unfamiliarity with Return, trying something different than Print

Comment: Okay, in that case, remove the `return()`, and instead place `return list_1` outside the loop?

Comment: ah, that was easy.  Thank you.  I guess that leads to my 2nd question...is it even worth using a function here at all?  Id like to organize my code better, hence the practicing. Not sure how to make this particular piece more valuable by using a function.  Thanks!

Comment: No, functions rarely have any use unless you call them multiple times - code reuse.

Comment: Yes, making a function (with a good name!!!) makes code much easier to read and much easier to test. If you do it right, the code will be understandable to someone who doesn't know code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have an error in your return value for `foo()`.
Make sure you return the list out of your function. for example:

```
def foo():
    list_1 = []
    for x in range(10):
        text = int(input('list a number:'))#this should be inside the loop
        if text > 100:
            list_1.append(True)
        else:
            list_1.append(False)
    return(list_1) #you are passing list_1 after your for loop

bool_list = foo() #will pass return value in function
#print(list_1) this will throw an error!
print(bool_list) #bool_list was list_1 in foo()
```

Reading up on namespaces, it is critical for understanding funcitons. When you launch `foo()`, it will run its own code, but if you don't pass objects with a return value, you can't use it in other places.

Functions are absolutely essential for well maintained code. Anytime an operation is needed repeatedly, functions cut down on unnecessary lines of code. They also offer versatility when the same operation needs to be run many times but in slightly different ways. You could pass an argument through foo() specifying how many times you want to run through your for loop, for example.

Answer (score 1):

There's an almost unlimited number of ways that you can use functions. The main driver in your decision is whether or not you can reuse functionality or if it simplifies your code. So in essence, can I build this into a building block is the question you should ask yourself.

So in your example, say you have to take input in several different scenarios or you have to maybe evaluate a number of lists and provide print output.

You could separate things based on that:

```
def take_input(list):
    count = 0
    while count < 5:
        inputlist.append(int(input('list a number:')))
        count += 1

def print_output(list):
    outputlist = []
    for input in list:
        if input < 100:
            outputlist.append(True)
        else:
            outputlist.append(False)
    print(outputlist)

inputlist = []
take_input(inputlist)
print_output(inputlist)
```